# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed wildcard certificate ios8/9

Tags: ios, ssl, https, nsurlconnection, app-transport-security

I'm trying to call a public api with a valid Wildcar SSL certificate (bought) but the connection fail with error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “api.mydomain.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey={type = immutable, count = 1, values = (
>       0 :

The wildcard certificate cover allsubdomains : *.mydomain.com
The host that i'm trying to connect is : api.mydomain.com

I tryed to add exception to App Transport security but not work

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

How can fix the problem?

Comment: It is not an ATS issue, because otherwise it'd work on iOS 8. Could it be that iOS has troubles trusting your issuer's CA certificate? Try adding issuer's certificate and see if error is gone.

Comment: how can add a issuer's CA certificate ?

Comment: Typically opening a CA certificate file from web page or email (send it to yourself) brings an option to install it. It also can be added with iPhone Configuration Utility. Certificate itself should be available for download somewhere on issuer's site.